# Google Analytics using iframe parent as referrer for link

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics

Having an issue while updating a clients project.There are three sites, A, B and C, all on separate domains. Site A loads site B in an iframe with a link to site C. Through Google Analytics, when the link to site C is clicked, site B (the iframe) is listed as its referral source. The client would like site A (the iframes parent) to be the referral source. Is this possible?

Currently we just add a query string with site A's url on the link to site C for them to see which client site it is coming from, but they would like it more direct.

Comment: are the frame and parent on the same domain? if they are you could do some fancy cross page scripting to have the parent page do the redirect.

Comment: @Pamblan Thanks  all three are different domains, I have updated the question with this info.